# Spring Web Application takes forever to load

Tags: java, spring-boot, ufw

I am trying to host a Spring Boot Application with Digital Ocean. I started the server in the following way:

```
mvn clean install
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

The application is running fine, no errors or warning. I can ssh from my machine and to localhost from inside the VM.

Initially I thought that maybe the ufw is not setup, but at a closer look, when I run `sudo ufw status`, this is the output (I configure it from [shorturl.at/myBDM](http://shorturl.at/myBDM) until '*Allow port ranges via ufw*'):

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                   # accept Apache
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                   # accept HTTPS connections
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                   # OpenVPN server
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # accept Apache
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # accept HTTPS connections
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # OpenVPN server
```

When I am trying to acces from the browser :8080, it takes forever to load and then the browser displays that server is not responding. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out bu myself. You need to run `ufw allow 8080`. In this way, you allow tomcat to work. **Note:** On that website, there is a similar command, but it is on port 443 and the comment is about http traffic.

Thanks